# Query a m2m relation in django

Tags: python, django

I have a ORM in which there is a m2m relation like this:

```
class FlowKits(models.Model):
    kit = models.ForeignKey(Kit, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    trip_cost = models.IntegerField(default=0)


class Flow(models.Model):

    flow_name = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=0)
    kits = models.ManyToManyField(FlowKits)
```

How can I get the `trip_cost` of a Flow whose id = 10 and kit id = 18?

I tried the following but it just give me the Flow Object

```
    f_obj = Flow.objects.filter(id=10, kits__kit=18)
```

Comment: Do you want the trip_cost value of all instance of FlowKits that matches Kit_id=18 && Flow_id=10 ?

Comment: @BriseBalloches yes

Comment: @daniherrera How do I get `trip_cost` from this ?

Comment: @RahulSharma, I posted and answer ... more easy than a comment.

Comment: @BriseBalloches I am getting: django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'Flow' into field. Choices are: component_pm, flow, id, kit, kit_id, quantity, trip_cost

Answer (score 0):

This is the query you are looking for:

```py
qs = FlowKits.objects.filter(flow__id = 10, kit__id=18)
resunt=qs.values_list("trip_cost", flat=True)

# trip_cost list for flow=10 and kit=18
print(result)
```

The trick is to start querying by `FlowKits` model.